# "User with this email already exists." False Error Upon Signup in Django / React Application with Custom User

Tags: reactjs, django, redux

I am using redux to manage the state.

Email is the username for my custom user model.

```
Here is my django User model.

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Please provide an e-mail")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        # user.is_superuser = False
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True,  verbose_name='last login')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # username = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email



    objects = UserAccountManager()
```

Here is the User Serializer and below auth.js

```
"from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'name', 'password', ]
"

Here is the auth.js "export const signup = (name, email, password, re_password) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    re_password,
  });

  try {
    console.log("body: ", body);
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/`,
      body,
      config
    );

    console.log("res: ", res);
    dispatch({
      type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err);
    dispatch({
      type: SIGNUP_FAIL,
    });
  }
};"
```

No matter what, I am getting SIGNUP_FAIL. Postman gave the more specific error "User with this email already exists." no matter what email I use.

I have no idea what's wrong, login functionality works fine so the error is specific to the signup on the backend

Im expecting a new user to get their verification e-mail and emails that have not signed up before should not get this false error